# $\forall p\in P_{n}$, define $B(p)=\{x:p(x)=0\}$. Prove that $\bigcup_{p\in P_{n}}B(p)$ is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

The question is:

$\forall p\in P_{n}$, define $B(p)=\{x:p(x)=0\}$. Prove that $\bigcup_{p\in P_{n}}B(p)$ is countable.

I understand that I have define the height of the polynomial and eventually derive a sequence of integers. But how do I go about doing this in a formally written proof?

Can you help me also interpret this from logic to English - I feel that may help me understand how to develop a proof.

Answer (score 1):

$B(p)$ is finite, as $|B(p)| \le \deg(p)$.

A countable union of finite (or countable) sets is countable (note that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable, e.g.)